# What should I do with the content from my rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, editing-help

I added some more information to an answer (and corrected a typo) but my edits were rejected.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6973552

What should I do with the new information? Seems like too much for a comment, but too similar to the original answer to post as a new answer.

Comment: Post your own answer.